# How could I change a sentence using as ... as?

Tags: grammar

> The sentiments expressed in the tweets can be as accurate a measure as is found with precedental researches.

If I change this sentence into the following ones, which one would be correct?

1. The sentiments expressed in the tweets can be as accurate a measure as the sentiments that is found with precedental researches.
2. The sentiments expressed in the tweets can be as accurate a measure as a measure that is found with precedental researches.

Comment: 1 is understandable. About 2...I understand that as well not necessary to express it like that. Both are correct.

Comment: The first is not correct since there not a subject/verb agreement in the last *as* clause.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually *creating redundancy* by rephrasing the original sentence to your examples.

*As* has a definition as a *pronoun* in [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as):

> 3. as pronoun
>
> **that**, who, **which** —used after same or such

"that kind of fruit **as** maids call medlars — Shakespeare"

["I received the same grade **as** you did."](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/as)

> The sentiments expressed in the tweets can be as accurate a measure ***as (which/that)*** is found with precedental researches.

In No. 1 example, the antecedent of "as" is "a measure" and you can't rephrase using "the sentiments". "Are" is required after "sentiments that", not *is*.

No. 2 example is redundant as "a measure" is repeated.